# Wordpress - different post title on frontend than in url

Tags: wordpress, post, seo, title

I need to change Wordpress theme function.php file so it will show custom name for post on frontend which is different than the title in post editor/URL.

For instance: Post title in text editor/url is "New York" but on front end will be shown "New York - never sleeping city". The reason for this is to shorten URL to basic metadata and keep "fancy name" on frontend only (posts, archives, sitemap, search results...). For "fancy name" I would like to use SEO title from Yoast SEO plugin.

In my case the pages are based on Wordpress posts types. So I need to define somewhere pool of posts(pages) IDs which should not be affected. The best solution is also NOT to affect all descendant pages under listed IDs.

The question is how should I modify function.php file?

*Note for community: if you see my question as not clear, please write comment before you will mark my question as off-topic so I can tune it and make it better.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can place this code in the `functions.php` of your theme

```
function set_my_seo_title($title, $id)
{
    global $post;
    $seo_title=get_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);         
    return ((!empty($seo_title)&&$post->post_type=='post') ? $seo_title : $title);
}

add_filter('the_title', 'set_my_seo_title', 15, 2);
```

This will check if post got SEO title set. If yes, it will be used, if no - it will use regular post title.

Comment: That sounds great! If that is so simple ;-) I just tried it and Wordpress show error: `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in functions.php on line 27` and on line 27 is your code `return ((!empty(get_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true))) ? get_post_meta($id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true) : $title); ` Anyway, thank you for help so far! – Pavel 6 mins ago

Comment: @Pavel My bad, forgot about this thing with php earlier than 5.5. Edited. Try now.

Comment: Great! Now it works. However, I did not realise that it affects also pages which means that my menu is full of long title names which makes menu items overflow. So I would like to kindly ask you to modify code for posts only! Thank you for help on this Flyer! You are king ;-)

Comment: Thank you Flyer ;-) I did try it, but it again affects also pages as you can see here http://snag.gy/m57Uo.jpg :-( I did try to clean cache and different browsers and issue is everywhere. Any other idea?

Comment: @Pavel Are you sure these things there are actually pages and not posts?  Cause I tested it and it works fine for me.

Comment: That is strange. They are really page :-( I have idea. Can you modify code so It will exclude certain pool of pages IDs? I guess that it should work then ☺

Comment: Replace `$post->post_type=='post'` with `!in_array($id,array(comma separated list of ids))`

Comment: Great, now it works! ;-) I do not know why, but Wordpress is somehow marking my pages as post type, therefore it did not work before. May be it is some historical reason (pages were created few years ago). Anyway. Last question. Do you think it is possible to change the code that also all descendant pages will be automatically excluded if their parent page has been excluded manualy by ID in your array? It is quite uncomfy to write down hundreds of IDs in array... Thanks.