# WordPress Post title filter and SEO title precedence

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filtering

I have some custom post types, which have their own .php file/template. In this I add some customizations to the title, so that it displays the $title+text.

What I need to accomplish now is two fold.

1. prepend and append some text to the actual `<title>` tag. So that it would look like `<title>my text + original title + more text</title>`
2. we have yoast seo plugin - we need this title to take precedence if someone goes in and inputs a specific title by hand. This should take precedence over the custom title for #1

Any help would be most appreciated.

I think this may be close to the solution:
[Wordpress - different post title on frontend than in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842779/wordpress-different-post-title-on-frontend-than-in-url)

Comment: Well, the link you attached seems like a fair solution, no? Why wouldn't you implement it as well?
And also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?.. If they already got their own .php file/template, then you could simply append your desired text within their files, no? Or maybe i misunderstood you..

Comment: @GonrasKarols - I found that after I posted. I did achieve the title on the post change with the template. However the <title>tag is in the header, requiring a filter right?

Comment: What kind of filter? Im still not sure i fully understood your question..

Answer (score 0):

I could not seem to accomplish this with a filter. So I wrote some simple JS for the single-page.php template.

```
document.title="some text"+<%php $title %>+"other text";
```

Which makes the title tag:

```
<title>some text Original Title other text</title>
```